# How do I navigate through a dictionary like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I found the following dictionary:

```
catalog = {"threads":{"39894014":{"date":1390842451,"r":0,"i":0,"lr":  {"id":39894014},"semantic_url":"the-g-wiki-g-is-for-the-discussion-  of-technology","sticky":1,"closed":1,"capcode":"mod"}}
```

I know I could access "date" for example by writing `data["threads"]["39894014"]["date"]`, but is there some way of skipping the second thing (`["39894014"]`,) because this number is randomly generated so the list may change, and it would be a totally different number.

Comment: This is not Python syntax; `var` looks like JavaScript to me.

Comment: yes, because it is, I tried to access it through json (just ignore the var catalog)

Comment: If there are few entries inside that dictionary under the key `threads`, how do you tell which one you need?

Comment: Then why include the `var` at all? Just focus on the issue of accessing the nested dictionary in Python, it doesn't matter how you loaded it.

Comment: I would try to get all of the entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to loop over the keys or values of the dictionary value of the `'threads'` key; if there is only ever *one* thread in the dictionary, you can extract that one dictionary with:

```
thread = next(data['threads'].values())
print(thread['date'])
```

If you don't need the outer dictionary to remain pristine, you could just use [`dict.popitem()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) to unwrap:

```
threadid, thread = data['threads'].popitem()
print(thread['date'])
```

To get *all* entries you can loop and grab the dates:

```
all_dates = [thread['data'] for thread in data['threads'].values()]
```

Comment: TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing
What did I do wrong?

Comment: @IThelp: mea culpa, Python 2 vs. Python 3 tripping me up there. Corrected.

Comment: Why not use `next(data['threads'].values())`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Yeah, a better idea.